# How to order by in two PHP MySQL queries that are related?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, distinct

I am creating a dropdown select form based on the results from two cross-referenced MySQL queries, however I cannot get the list to order by alphabet correctly.

I am taking an ID number from the first table "list1", but then need to get its name from the second table "list2", and display them alphabetically.

I tried the ORDER BY, but it does not make sense in either query really.

```
    <select name="select">
        <?php
        $sql       = "SELECT DISTINCT id FROM list1"; 
        $query     = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die (mysqli_error()); 

        while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
            $id        = $row["id"];
            // *** get the ID name from second table ***
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM list2 WHERE id='$id' ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 1"; 
            $query2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2) or die (mysqli_error()); 

            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) { 
                $name = $row2["name"];
                echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
            } // end while

            // *** end get name ***

        } // end while
        ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine the two queries into one:

```
select col1, col2 etc
from list2 where list2.id in (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM list1)
order by name asc
```

This gives you the same list you would have gotten to using your queries and subsequent sub-queries but does it one go and you can order the whole result as needed.

```
<select name="select">
<?php
  $sql2 = "    select col1, col2 etc
    from list2 where list2.id in (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM list1)
    order by name asc
"; 
  $query2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2) or die (mysqli_error()); 
  while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) { 
  $name = $row2["name"];
  echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
  } // end while
?>
</select>
```

Just note that you should probably not use `select *` when joining tables like this. Just pick the columns you want.